# pass data from one from to another in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

In android we can use intent to pass data from one Acitivity to another .

Generally I use showForm("formname",null) method to shift form.

Is there any class for passing data from one form to another in codenameone ?

And how can I pass data to another form in codenameone?

Answer (score 4):

Just store the data in the state machine class as variables. You can also add the data to the navigation stack using the methods `getFormState`/`setFormState` but that's not essential.

Comment: As per my understanding , setFormState And getFormState is used for saving the state of a form  when moving to other form and resume the state . And I want to pass some data(like string as username)  from Form1 to Form2 .

For example :
I have Form1 which has Username texifield  in which user type his name and click Next button Then I want to pass the username string to Form2 .
How can I do this in codenameone?

Comment: As I said just store the variables in the class for that case. In the before* event initialize based on the values of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data to another form without the GUI Builder you can use getters and setters.

To pass data e.g username from Form A to Form B, create a private variable username in Form B and create getters and setters for the variable.
Then create an instance of Form B in Form A and call the setter method for variable username (setUsername method in Form B) and pass the data as a parameter, and lastly call the show() function on Form B

In Form B:

```
class FormB extends Form {

private String username;

public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String name) {
    this.username = name;
}
```

}

In Form A:

```
class FormA extends Form {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String someName = "Aiotouch Softwares";
    Form nextForm = new FormB();
    nextForm.setUsername(someName);
    nextForm.show();
}
```

}